# Bash for loop containing python script

Tags: python, bash, loops, for-loop

New here!

I'm trying to loop a python script in bash that gets stats from fastq files. I want it to loop through all the fastq files in a directory and save the outputs in a text file. Ideally don't want to edit the python script

This is the script that works when I'm not looping it:

```
python pythonscript.py -i fastqfile1.fq -q > stats1.txt
```

This is the loop that doesn't work for me:

```
for f in *.fq; do python pythonscript.py -i "$f" -q;
do echo "${f%.*}" > "stats${f%.fq}.txt" done
```

Thank you

EDIT I have put the loop in a bash .sh script. The error message I get is " looping_script.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `do' looping_script.sh: line 5:` do' "

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "doesn't work for me"?

Comment: sorry should have said! I get this: looping_script.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
looping_script.sh: line 5: `do'

Comment: Do you want all the results in one single file, or the results from each Python run in a separate file?

Comment: I have another code that puts all the .txt files in one file, so either way!

Comment: At the very least, you are missing a semicolon before `done` (which is only a keyword when it appears as the name of a command; here, it's just another argument to `echo` syntactically).

Comment: The second `do` isn't doing anything useful; `do` only introduces the *body* of a `for` loop, not every command in the body of the loop individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this if you want all results in a single file:

```
for f in *.fq; do 
   python pythonscript.py -i "$f" -q
done > results.txt
```